# "Punishment" for downvoting late answers in review queue when around 500 rep

Tags: discussion

I guess this is an issue that does not effect a lot of people, but I would still like to raise this point. If you're in the review queue for late answers and there's an accepted late answer which you think deserves to be downvoted, and you're at exactly 500 rep, there's an incentive to **not** downvote it. Losing that single point will also make you lose the privilege to access the review queue.

Isn't it more fair to disable the "loose a point when you downvote" in a small range around the 500 rep?

Comment: Votes in meta are many times used to express disagreement with the premise of a post (besides their usual meaning). Particularly so in questions tagged `feature-request`. But worry not, votes in meta do not affect your account or reputation.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation @yivi. I wasn't aware of the different culture at meta.

Comment: "... if [*reasons*] there's an incentive to **not** downvote [this downvote-worthy post]" – you should downvote a post for its quality, not for any external reasons. In this case the inverse also goes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @usr2564301 . I was also aiming for discussion, more than I really wanted to do a feature request. (I've removed the `feature-request` tag now for that reason) I do agree with you! But I also think it is weird somewhere to have the buzz of getting a new privilege, after which you follow the instructions how to participate in the review queue and then suddenly - *in the middle of the queue* - you get a notice that says that you can't continue any more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just earn a bit more reputation doing other tasks.

Even editing will give you rep still.

But asking and answering questions will quickly elevate you from that thereshold, so you can down-vote whenever you feel is appropriate.

Disabling the downvote cost at any of the privileges thresholds would give a lot of users the ability to downvote answers for free, and would make the thresholds less meaningful.

Comment: That seems to be the way I guess.   It felt weird to suddenly lose the privilege when just following the recommendations on the screen.

Comment: @axm__ You've only spent 64 points for downvoting so far. Not quite a lot. Around 13% of your current rep. I've spent more than 1k at this point. Not a lot for many users, but a good 30% of my actual rep. Better not to think of it. You earn some, you lose some.

Comment: Thank you for that comment. That puts it in perspective.  I've motivated the reason for the question a bit more in a comment on the question. It was weird being kicked out of the queue in the middle of doing what was recommended.

Comment: "would make the thresholds less meaningful" downvotes are free in questions. The only reason why downvotes cost on answers is to make sure people have strong opinions that make them worthy of the costs (ie. not just a spat or strategic voting).