# Lost "Edit questions and answers" by downvoting an answer: Inconsistent reputation?

Tags: bug, edits, reputation

When trying to work on some low quality answers, it seems I lost my new achievement to edit answers:

[image: Screen shot]

The status display looks inconsistent (2001 reputation vs. < 2k).
Is that a bug?

Comment: You're at 1999 reputation points now. [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) requires 2000. Note that the reputation points displayed on the topbar is deceptive. It will always show a new value on an increase, but it will never show a decrease. You need to refresh the page to view the accurate value.

Comment: You can lose privileges if you lose reputation. Since some review queues allow you to vote, and downvoting answers costs rep, it can happen. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375566/punishment-for-downvoting-late-answers-in-review-queue-when-around-500-rep), for example. Regarding the reputation in the top bar, it's simply that is hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: So the game will repeat a few times (getting above 2k and going below again)?

Comment: Hopefully it won't ever repeat, because you'll post a couple of stellar answers later today earning you tons of rep, never to be on the 2k threshold again.

Comment: OK, maybe my work or question from today will be credited...

Comment: If you got that downvote right and others agree to delete that answer, your -1 will be refunded, bringing you back to 2K. No stellar answers needed ....

Comment: @yivi Yes, it does.

Comment: @rene Do not say that. We do need those stellar answers.

Comment: This is what my rep history looks like on a typical review day: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cATzw.png

Comment: @rene This looks like serial voting .... :P

Comment: @Tom I'm certainly serial voting but I can't help first posts and late answers are filled with utter garbage that takes 3 seconds to evaluate. I hope the review taks algorithm doesn't visit a profile and then submit all posts to the queue ... otherwise I'm screwed as I don't pay attention to who posted.

Comment: @U.Windl *"So the game will repeat a few times"* - yep. I will be brutally honest and admit that I stopped downvoting answers every time I was exactly at a specific reputation unlock point until I had at least a couple dozen reputation points to spare again. It's kind of robotic how it works, but on the other hand it's also just honest and simple to understand/maintain.